# sscanf() returns part of previous lines data

Tags: c, fgets, scanf

Given a text file for 4 lines: Separated by a comma(,) as the delimiter. I am locating the specific ISBN by using fgets to grab each line and comparing the ISBN (978-xxxxxxxxxx) with the one the user gave. This works fine.

Even when fgets() to the last line of the file. It still returns the correct information. However, as I am trying to filter each element of the string into its respected struct member to send over socket. The last element returns everything correct up until the last 4 elements/fields. This error does not occur with any but the last line of the file.

I assumed that this was an EOF error, however I am not to well versed on sscanf() to understand why that is.

If I were to print out *linebuf*, it returns the correct (un-parsed) line.
But if I print out all my data. It return part of the third line's data. Specifically, *edition*, *number of copies*, *available copies*

```
9780132126953,Andrew Tanenbaum & David Wetherall,Computer Networks,5,2011,Prentice-Hall,5,2
9780123745408,Michael Donahoo & Kenneth Calvert,TCP/IP Sockets in C,2,2009,Morgan Kaufman,3,0
9780133354690,William Stallings,Cryptography and Network Security,6,2014,Prentice-Hall,3,3
9780072467505,Yale Patt & Sanjay Patel,Introduction to Computing Systems from bits & gates to C & beyond 2,2004,McGraw-Hill,1,0
```

MY CODE:

```
while (fgets(linebuf, 1024, file) != NULL) {
    sscanf(linebuf, "%[^,], %[^,], %[^,], %u, %u, %[^,], %u, %u\n", 
        bufferISBN, bufferAuthor, bufferTitle, 
        &bufferEdition, &bufferYear, bufferPublisher, 
        &bufferInventory, &bufferAvailable
    );

    if (strcmp(temp->isbn, bufferISBN) == 0) { // found correct line, add data to struct
        mssg.respType = Okay; // enum
        mssg.requestID = temp->requestID;
        strcpy(mssg.isbn, bufferISBN); // needs fixing
        strcpy(mssg.authors, bufferAuthor);
        strcpy(mssg.title, bufferTitle);
        strcpy(mssg.publisher, bufferPublisher);
        mssg.edition = bufferEdition;
        mssg.year = bufferYear;
        mssg.inventory = bufferInventory;                          
        mssg.available = bufferAvailable;   
    }
```

NOTE the format of sscanf(), I'm not sure if that is correct as well:

```
"%[^,], %[^,], %[^,], %u, %u, %[^,], %u, %u\n"
```

I am also aware of the ton of *buffer* variables I am using.

EDIT: When I limit the length of the title. It returns fine. Why is this?

Comment: You should really check the return value of sscanf

Comment: I have, the problem I am facing now, is when I strcpy() over bufferISBN to mssg.isbn. The ISBN+title are stored. However if I print out bufferISBN, it only returns the ISBN

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the newline is left off the last line of a text file.  To check, do `od -t x1 <filename>` and the last char should be `0a`

If it's not, you can use a text editor to clean the file and add the newline.

Or, you can change your code slightly to handle this:

```
while (fgets(linebuf, 1024, file) != NULL) {
    char *cp = strchr(linebuf, '\n');
    if (cp != NULL)
        *cp = 0;
    sscanf(linebuf, "%[^,], %[^,], %[^,], %u, %u, %[^,], %u, %u",
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the result of `sscanf()` until checking the return value

```
if (8 != sscanf(linebuf, "%[^,], %[^,], %[^,], %u, %u, %[^,], %u, %u\n", 
    bufferISBN, bufferAuthor, bufferTitle, 
    &bufferEdition, &bufferYear, bufferPublisher, 
    &bufferInventory, &bufferAvailable
    )) Handle_Error();
```

In this case, the return value is not affected by what is scanned after the last `"%u"`. To insure everything was scanned as expected, use `"%n"` which saves the number of `char` scanned, if that format specifier is reached.

```
int n = 0;
sscanf(linebuf, "%[^,], %[^,], %[^,], %u, %u, %[^,], %u, %u %n", 
    bufferISBN, bufferAuthor, bufferTitle, 
    &bufferEdition, &bufferYear, bufferPublisher, 
    &bufferInventory, &bufferAvailable,
    &n);
if (n == 0) Handle_Scan_Incomplete();
if (linebuf[n] != '\0') Handle_Scan_Extra();
```

Note that `'\n'` and `' '` as a format directive do the same thing: scan 0 or more white-space.

Note: space before non-`"%c"`,`"%n"`,`"%[]"` is normally not needed as the other specifiers consume leading white-space.  Could use:

```
"%[^,], %[^,], %[^,],%u,%u, %[^,],%u,%u %n"
```

For uniformity, recommend a space at the start and width limits  (I did just `bufferISBN`)

```
char bufferISBN[14];
" %13[^,], %[^,], %[^,],%u,%u, %[^,],%u,%u %n"
```

Comment: I revised much of my code, however bufferISBN receives the ISBN plus the author.

     'AFTER SSCANF (PARSING):  9780123745408, Michael Donahoo & Kenneth Calvert, TCP/IP Sockets in C, 2, 2009, Morgan Kaufman, 3, 0' 


What it bufferISBN stores: _9780132126953Andrew Tanenbaum & David Wetherall_

Comment: Suspect your code does not correct width limits as in this answer `char bufferISBN[14]; " %13[^,],...`.  So 1) review needed `char` array sizes, 2) add width limits to format 3) report the return value of `sscanf()`